# ANTLR 3 parsing problem

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I have written an *ANTLR 3* grammar for parsing *TaskJuggler III* bookings files (see below).

On line

> project prj "Sample project" "1.0" 2010-10-24-00:00-+0200 - 2010-11-23-09:00-+0100 {

I'm getting following errors:

> line 1:42 mismatched character '-' expecting set '0'..'9'
>
> line 1:48 mismatched character ':' expecting set '0'..'9'
>
> line 1:67 mismatched character '-' expecting set '0'..'9'
>
> line 1:73 mismatched character ':' expecting set '0'..'9'

Thereafter, an *OutOfMemory* error occurs.

Here is the relevant part of the grammar:

> bookingsFile returns [DefaultBookingsFile bookingsFile]
>
> ```
> :
>
>     {
>
>         bookingsFile = new DefaultBookingsFile();
>
>     }
>
>     projectHeader
>
>     projectIds
>
>     (resourceDeclaration)*
>
>     (task)*
>
>     (
>
>         suppStmt=supplementStatement
> ```
>
> {bookingsFile.addSupplementStatement( $suppStmt.suppStmt ); }
>
> ```
>     )*
>
> ;
> ```
>
> projectHeader
>
> ```
> :
>
>     'project prj "' ANY_TEXT '" "1.0"' TJ3_BOOKING_TIME '-'
> ```
>
> TJ3_BOOKING_TIME '{'
>
> ```
>     '}'
>
> ;
> ```
>
> TJ3_BOOKING_TIME
>
> ```
> : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT
> ```
>
> '-' DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT '-' TIMEZONE
>
> ```
> ;
> ```
>
> TIMEZONE
>
> ```
> : ('+'|'-')DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT
>
> ;
> ```

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

P. S.: Full version of the grammar is available at

[http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dp-sw-dev/pcc/prototype1/files/head%3A/src/main/java/at/silverstrike/pcc/impl/tj3bookingsparser/grammar/](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Edp-sw-dev/pcc/prototype1/files/head%3A/src/main/java/at/silverstrike/pcc/impl/tj3bookingsparser/grammar/)

and below

```
grammar Bookings;
 
options {
    backtrack=true;
    memoize=true;
}

@header { 
package at.silverstrike.pcc.impl.tj3bookingsparser.grammar; 
}

@lexer::header {
package at.silverstrike.pcc.impl.tj3bookingsparser.grammar;
}


bookingsFile returns [DefaultBookingsFile bookingsFile]
    :
        {
            bookingsFile = new DefaultBookingsFile();
        }
        projectHeader
        projectIds
        (resourceDeclaration)*
        (task)*
        (
            suppStmt=supplementStatement {bookingsFile.addSupplementStatement( $suppStmt.suppStmt ); }
        )*
    ;
    
projectHeader
    :
        'project prj "' ANY_TEXT '" "1.0"' TJ3_BOOKING_TIME '-' TJ3_BOOKING_TIME '{' 
        '}' 
    ;
projectIds
    :
        'projectids prj'
    ;

resourceDeclaration
    :
        'resource' TJ3_IDENTIFIER TJ3_STRING
    ;

task
    :
        'task' TJ3_IDENTIFIER TJ3_STRING '{' ANY_TEXT '}'
    ;

supplementStatement returns [DefaultSupplementStatement suppStmt]
    :
        {
            suppStmt = new DefaultSupplementStatement();
        }
        'supplement task' taskId=TJ3_DOTTED_TASK_IDENTIFIER { suppStmt.setTaskId($taskId.text); } 
        '{' 
        (
            bStmt=bookingStatement {suppStmt.addBookingStatement( $bStmt.stmt ); }
        )*
        ANY_TEXT
        '}'
    ;

bookingStatement returns [DefaultBookingStatement stmt]
    :
    {
        stmt = new DefaultBookingStatement();
    }
        TJ3_IDENTIFIER ':' 
        'booking' 
        resource=TJ3_IDENTIFIER { stmt.setResource($resource.text); } 
        ib1=indBooking { stmt.addIndBooking($ib1.indBooking); } 
        (
            ',' 
            ib2=indBooking { stmt.addIndBooking($ib2.indBooking); }
        )* 
        overTimeEtc
    ;

indBooking returns [DefaultIndBooking indBooking]
    :
        startTime=TJ3_BOOKING_START_TIME '+' duration=TJ3_DURATION 'h' 
            {
                $indBooking = new DefaultIndBooking($startTime.text, $duration.text);
            }
    ;

overTimeEtc
    :
        '{' ANY_TEXT '}'
    ;

TJ3_IDENTIFIER
    : ('a'..'Z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'Z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

DIGIT
    : '0'..'9'
    ;

TJ3_STRING
    : '"' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|' '|'_')* '"'
    ;

ANY_TEXT
    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|' '|'_')*
    ;
    
TJ3_DOTTED_TASK_IDENTIFIER
    : TJ3_IDENTIFIER ('.' TJ3_IDENTIFIER)*
    ;

TJ3_BOOKING_TIME
    : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT '-' TIMEZONE 
    ;

TJ3_BOOKING_START_TIME
    : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT ('-' DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT)? (TIMEZONE)?;

TIMEZONE
    : ('+'|'-')DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT
    ;

TJ3_DURATION
    : FP_VALUE ('min' | 'h' | 'd' | 'w' | 'm' | 'y')
    ;

FP_VALUE
    : DIGIT+
    | DIGIT* '.' DIGIT*
    ;
```

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) when removing all custom Java code (the stuff between the `{` and `}`), does the error also appear? 2) Is there a particular reason you're using `backtrack=true;`? Setting `backtrack=true;` might cause the error and can probably be replaced with predicates before the rules that require backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

> 2) Is there a particular reason you're using backtrack=true;? 

I removed "backtrack=true" and the error still occurs.

I'll try to remove Java code and will tell you the results.

Comment: Thanks again for the hints!

When I remove

a) the code between curly brackets and
b) the code between square brackets,

the errors do not occur.

If I remove the code between the curly brackets (only a, but not b), the error occurs.

So I conclude that I did something wrong with the return statements, e. g.


bookingsFile returns [DefaultBookingsFile bookingsFile]

Do you have an idea what may be wrong with it?

Comment: @user399457, then my guess is there's a loop (or recursive call) that never terminates in your code causing the OutOfMemory error. You're welcome, of course! :)

Comment: @user399457, if you've resolved the issue, and the error was in your custom code, you might want to remove this question since it was/is not ANTLR related.

Comment: No, the issue isn't resolved yet. And I'm not sure that it is my code, which causes the error because the infinite loop occurs during reading of the tokens in the "projectHeader" part. I intend to investigate this issue during the weekend.

Comment: Now I tried it again. Even when I remove Java code from the grammar, the error still occurs. :(

Comment: Could you post a small, self contained, example that I (or someone else) can run that exhibits the behavior you describe?

Comment: You can find my answer at http://sw-dev.at/resources/2010_10_31_pcc/2010_10_31_pcc_parsing.txt (I don't know how to format my messages correctly on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule:

```
TJ3_BOOKING_START_TIME
  :  DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT ('-' DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT)? (('+'|'-')DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT)?
  ;
```

does not match this part of your input:

```
" ... 2010-10-25-00:00-+0200 ... "
//                    ^^
```

The `-+` part is not accounted for in your rule.

**EDIT**

Try something like this:

```
grammar Bookings;

bookingsFile
  :  Project Prj String String Time Hyphen Time OpenParen CloseParen EOF
  ;

Project
  :  'project'
  ;

Prj
  :  'prj'
  ;

OpenParen
  :  '{'
  ;

CloseParen
  :  '}'
  ;

Hyphen
  :  '-'
  ;

String
  :  '"' ~'"'* '"'
  ;

Time
  :  D D D D '-' D D '-' D D '-' D D ':' D D '-+' D D D D
  ;  

fragment    
D
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;

Space   
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r'? '\n'){$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

Interpreting the source:

```
project prj "Sample project" "1.0" 2010-10-25-00:00-+0200-2010-11-24-09:00-+0100 {
}
```

yields the parse-tree:

[image]

HTH